# Повторение цикла при неправильном вводе данных

Tags: c++, c, if, циклы, пароль

Представьте, есть цель-определить верно ли вводимое пользователем или нет.Если вводимое не верно, то цикл повторяется заново, иначе, если вводимые данные верны, программа выполняет что-либо или просто заканчивается. Как это сделать? Я самолично пытался написать с помощью цикла for и/или условного оператора if(код дать не могу, не сохранился). Проблема в том, как осуществить повтор одного и того-же действия. Спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ну давайте прикинем. Итак, смысл примерно такой:

```
Начало
    Ввод
    Проверка
    Если неверно
        Вывести сообщение
        Перейти в Начало
```

Вроде бы так?

Перевести в цикл - раз плюнуть:

```
for(;;)
{
    Ввод данных
    Проверка
    if (верно) break;
    Вывести сообщение
}
```

Можно и другие циклы использовать.

Надеюсь, код для всех этих `Ввод данных`, `Проверка` и т.д. - написать труда не составит?

Comment: Извините, я уже понял

Comment: цикл `for` имеет вид `for(инициализация;условие;последействие) { тело }` и работает так: выполняется инициализация, `Метка:` проверяется условие. Если не выполнено - выход из цикла. Если выполнено - выполняется тело, потом постусловие и переход к `Метке` - проверка условия и далее... Можно убрать любую из частей в заголовке. Очевидно, что отсутствие условия рассматривается как выполненное (иначе в цикле нет смысла). Так что `for(;;)` - бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: Ну, если ответ вас устраивает - закрывайте вопрос, помечая ответ как принятый...

Answer (score 2):

Через цикл *do  {} while();*

do {
       Ввести данные.

} while (Данные == или != Значению или >,< Значения);

Пример C# возраст в промежутке двух чисел.
Пока значение меньше 14 или больше 85 повторять ввод данных.

```
int digit;
do {
    Console.WriteLine("Введите возраст: ");
    Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out digit);
} while(digit < 14 || digit > 85);
Console.WriteLine(digit);
```

Answer (score 1):

Перед циклом инициализируем флаг и присваиваем ему значение `false`.
Во время выполнения цикла верное значение отмечаем флагом `true`, неверное - `false`.
Для выхода из цикла флаг должен быть помечен как `true`.

```
    using System;
    class HelloWorld
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        bool EnterIsCorrect = false;

        do 
        {
            int number;
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Сколько будет 2 + 2");
                string strnumber = Console.ReadLine();
                number = int.Parse(strnumber);
            }

            if (number == 4)
            {
                EnterIsCorrect = true;
            }
            else
            {
                EnterIsCorrect = false;
            }
        } while (EnterIsCorrect == false);
```