# Как сделать завершение цикла?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне нужно сделать выход по нажатию определенной кнопки, как сделать?

```
int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    srand(time(NULL));

    while (1)
    {
        int x, y, Xk, Xn, sum = 0, k, count = 0;
        bool find = false;
        cout << "Введите размерность массива (x, y): ";
        while (!(cin >> x) || (cin.peek() != '\n' || !(x>0))) //проверка на корректность ввода
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
        }
        while (!(cin >> y) || (cin.peek() != '\n' || !(y>0))) //проверка на корректность ввода
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
        }
        cout << "Введите диапазон чисел, для заполнения массива (Xn, Xk): ";
        while (!(cin >> Xn) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) //проверка на корректность ввода
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
        }
        while (!(cin >> Xk) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) //проверка на корректность ввода
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
        }
        int **mas = new int*[x];//создание массива
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            mas[i] = new int[y];
        cout << "Начальный массив => " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) //заполнение массива и вывод
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                mas[i][j] = (rand() % Xk) + Xn;
                cout << mas[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << "Введите K: ";
        while (!(cin >> k) || (cin.peek() != '\n')) //проверка на корректность ввода
        {
            cin.clear();
            while (cin.get() != '\n');
            cout << "Введено недопустимое значение. Повторите попытку." << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) //заполнение массива и вывод
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                if (i + j == k)
                {
                    sum += mas[i][j];
                    find = true;
                    count++;
                    cout << "Элемент с индексом [" << i << "]+[" << j << "]=" << k << " к сумме добавил " << mas[i][j] << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        if (find == true)
            cout << "Сумма " << count << " элементов для которых [i]+[j]=" << k << " равна " << sum << endl;
        else
            cout << "Таких элементов для которых [i]+[j]=" << k << " нет" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Асинхронно? Т.е. - ожидание ввода, но вы нажимаете что-то там - и программа завершается?

Comment: Я хочу что бы первый раз он просто ввёл данные, а потом в конце, ему выводится текст, если хотите продолжить работу введите цифру или букву, просто я не знаю как записать.

Comment: Ну в нужном месте запрашивайте какой-то определенный ввод для продолжение, проверяйте. Если выход - используйте `break`, продолжение - `continue`...

Comment: Вот так?
While ( c != 0)
{
   kod
   cout << "Для завершение работы программы нажмите 0"
   cin >> c;
}
cout << "Текст";
return 0;
Вот так правильно будет?

Comment: Я не знаю как написать правильно. Помогите дураку понять как сделать.

Comment: Гляньте тут - по сути, аналог вашего вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/661505/195342 Только и разницы, что у вас проверка, не верно ли введено, а - надо ли ввести еще.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю и разберусь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На вопрос в комментарии

Вот так? `While ( c != 0) { kod cout << "Для завершение работы программы нажмите 0" cin >> c; } cout << "Текст"; return 0;` Вот так правильно будет?

Нет, потому что `cin>>c` считывает символ. А он не `0`, а `'0'`.

Так что правильно

```
char c = '0';
while( с != '0')
{
    // Работаем

    cout << "Для продолжения работы введите 0: ";
    cin >> c;
}
```

И учтите, что `cin >> c` требует не только нажать клавишу скажем с 0, но и потом нажать Enter.

Comment: А как сделать так, что бы пользователь нажал клавишу и программа закрылась?